# A weird Error object is being logged to console

Tags: node.js, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to post comments through the youtube API, but they are returning an error upon trying.

When I log the error object I get

```
{ [Error: Bad Request] code: 400 }
```

The first part of which looks weird (key-value inside array?)

I tried to log the keys of the object and it only returns `code`

Supposely the API return a much more detailed message, but it's like it's 'hidden' inside the `[Error: Bad Request]`, which I dont know how to access

Answer (score 0):

That's just how Node formats errors.

Try it yourself in a node console:

```
var e = new Error("Test");
e.code = 500
console.log(e); // Outputs: { [Error: Test] code: 500 }
```

As far as your issue with the YouTube API, I suggest creating a different question on StackOverflow about your issues, providing more information around how you are calling the API.